# vue js not displaying nested json

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My vue.js code is unable to access a reference in a returned json object.

The vue.js code

```
new Vue({
    el: '#axios',
    data: function() {
      return {
        bikes: null,
        baseurl: "https://" + document.querySelector('#axios').dataset.hostportname + "/",

      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'api/v1/bicycles',
        baseURL: this.baseurl
      })
        .then(response => {
          this.bikes = response.data
          console.log("now bikes are " + JSON.stringify(this.bikes[0].owner.userName));
        }) 
        .catch(error => console.log("There is an error getting bikes: " + error))
    }
  })
```

If the HTML file (just a part) is

```
<div id="axios" th:data-hostportname="${hostportname}">
    <li v-for="bike in bikes" :key="bike.id">
        {{ bike.make }} -------  {{ bike.owner }}   
    </li> 
</div>
```

Then the html output is

```
dawes --------  { "id": 1, "userName": "user1"}  
whyte --------  { "id": 2, "userName": "user2"}  
whyte --------  { "id": 3, "userName": "user3"}
```

And the console.log output is

> now bikes are "user1"

if I try to output the owner id alone

```
<div id="axios" th:data-hostportname="${hostportname}">
    <li v-for="bike in bikes" :key="bike.id">
        {{ bike.make }} ------  {{ bike.owner.id }}   
    </li> 
</div>
```

no output with a console error of

`TypeError: "bike.owner is undefined"`

So the Axios code is returning the correct data. Each object in the array is accessible. But the nested object within each array member is not accessible at a field level.

Just to make clear, if I ask for {{ bike.owner }} then I get a displayed the oener record that is referenced by the bike record. If I ask for {{ bile.owner.id }} then I get the console.log error of bike.owner is undefined and nothing is displayed. So I don't see how this is a loading problem unless bike.owner.id takes longer to retrieve than bike.owner, even though the latter displays.

Can someone explain what I am misunderstanding?

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried adding a conditional "{{ bike && bike.owner ? bike.owner.id : "" }}" ?

Comment: change the value of your bikes:null into bikes: [ {owner:{}}]

Comment: Seems like a race condition problem. The template is trying to show bike.owner.id before the axios complete the request.

Comment: According to @ChristhoferNatalius I would add a `v-if` to that block. Should solve the problem.

Comment: you have written the output to be... `dawes --------  { "id": 1, "userName": "user1"}` a bit unclear, so is the output actuially `[{dawes: {id: 1, username: "user1"}}]`. If that is the case, there is no `owner` property.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius - if that is the case, then why does the whole object show (including owner details) if just output {{bike}} or {{bike.owner}} ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 - sorry but what bikes: null ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 - ah you mean the js file! Will try that.

Comment: Can you show the output of console.log(response.data) ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 - that made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Get the type of that. Maybe it is string.

Comment: @John Unless there is something wrong with the response.data, what usually happen to me is because `{{ undefined }}` doesn't throws error and print nothing, so it does not throw error when printing undefined `bike.owner`. And when axios done, `bike.owner` is updated to have `id` and `userName` and it is automatically printed. However it will throw error and stop the script when accessing attribute `id` when `bike.owner` is still undefined (before the axios call is completed) and nothing has printed.

Comment: Usually, I wrap the v-for inside a v-if="!loading", and showing loading animation when loading. So I do `this.loading = true` before axios call, and do `this.loading = false` in axios.finally

Comment: I will have a play with this later but when I display {{ bike  }} outside of the loop or {{ bike }} within the loop, everything that I expect is displayed, which suggests it is loaded. Or is that not correct - data can be displayed even though it is not loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the root cause and it had nothing to do with vue.

Basically I have two models - owners and bicycles. Bicycles have a ref to a single owner. And owners have ref to an array of bicycles. I added @JsonIdentityInfo to both. And that was my problem.

Changing this to having @JsonIdentityInfo only in owner then allowed it to work.

Many thanks for all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the response you are getting is as follows where owner is also a string.
So you might have to parse it before assigning it to bikes.

```
[{
    make: 'one',
    owner: '{ "id": 1, "userName": "user1"}'
}, {
    make: 'two',
    owner: '{ "id": 2, "userName": "user2"}'
}, {
    make: 'three',
    owner: '{ "id": 3, "userName": "user2"}'
}]
```

Hope this helps.

**Update 1**

Can you try adding a loading flag?
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

```
new Vue({
    el: '#axios',
    data: function() {
      return {
        bikes: null,
        loading: true
        baseurl: "https://" + document.querySelector('#axios').dataset.hostportname + "/",
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'api/v1/bicycles',
        baseURL: this.baseurl
      })
        .then(response => {
          this.bikes = response.data
          console.log("now bikes are " + JSON.stringify(this.bikes[0].owner.userName));
        }) 
        .catch(error => console.log("There is an error getting bikes: " + error)).finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
  })
```

And add `v-if` to your block

```
<div id="axios" v-if="!loading" th:data-hostportname="${hostportname}">
    <li v-for="bike in bikes" :key="bike.id">
        {{ bike.make }} ------  {{ bike.owner.id }}   
    </li> 
</div>
```

Comment: But it is not a string. It is a reference to another model so I don't thik that is the problem.  Note the console log in the vue file, that prints out fine.

Comment: Have you also checked all the entries in the array? I mean do each object in the array have a property as owner?
I know this is a silly question but I am out of clue now.

Comment: Made changes re your code and same problem - console.log shows bike.owner is undefined. The thing I do not understand is that if I display bike.owner then it shows the owner record. But if I show bike.owner.id then "bike.owner is undefined". Which is why I do not think it is a loading problem because bike.owner shows id (and userName, etc etc) but bike.owner.id is just a drill down into bike.owner (is it?)